# Is Olympus Tough TG-5 battery charger just a regular USB charger?

Tags: battery, olympus, usb, charger

The battery charger that I got with my Olympus Tough TG-5 (left) looks pretty different from any typical USB charger that you see here in Europe (right).

[image: USB chargers]

But in spite of its somewhat unusual and bulky appearance, it seems to work just like any other 5V 1.5A USB charger. I can use it to charge a mobile phone, and more importantly, I seem to be able to use any modern USB charger to charge the battery of the camera.

So is there anything special about the Olympus charger? Is it really just a normal USB charger?

The user manual is unhelpful; as usual, it instructs against using any third-party charger, but this is what you find in the manual of any mobile phone, too.

Comment: Most USB chargers are not UL listed. That's a potentially important difference in terms of the likelihood it causes a fire. Sure anecdotally, most cheap USB chargers don't start a fire, but the potential downside risk includes death.

Answer (score 1):

According to this YouTube video, [Olympus TG-4: Does It Charge with USB? | FAQ Video](https://youtu.be/9VEk5z4N5X0?t=29s) (queued to 29 seconds), yes, it does charge with USB.

Comment: Thank you for queueing the video to the right spot, so we don't have to wait through a bunch of stuff to get to the information.

Comment: @scottbb TG-5 has got a standard micro-USB connector.

Comment: @JukkaSuomela Indeed, you're absolutely correct. My mistake